# How to pass reactive data to Vue components using pinia store elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-reactivity, pinia

- ***GamePage.vue***

Destructured the pinia state elements and action method

```
const $store = useGameStore();
const {game, teamOne, teamTwo} = storeToRefs($store);
const { getGame } = $store;
```

Passed the destructed variables to components

```
<player-stat-table
  :title="teamTwo.name"
  :players="teamTwo.players"
  :teamColor="teamTwo.team_color"
 />
```

- ***Table Display***

[image: table]

- ***store/game_store.js***

I am trying to edit data from the above table using updatePlayer action, after successfully completing the action I am updating the entire store data by recalling the get action method. But the data in the table is not updating reactively, it's updating after page reload. How to update it reactively?

```
import { api } from 'boot/axios'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

import { splitPlayers } from 'src/helpers'

export const useGameStore = defineStore('game', {
  state: () => ({
    game: null,
    teamOne: null,
    teamTwo: null,
  }),

  getters: {
    getTeamOne: state => state.teamOne,
    getTeamTwo: state => state.teamTwo,
    getGameData: state => state.game,
  },

  actions: {
    getGame(payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api.get(`/games/${payload.gameID}/`)
        .then(resp => {
          const data = resp.data;
          const teams = splitPlayers(data)
          this.game = data
          this.teamOne = teams[0]
          this.teamTwo = teams[1]
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
    },
    updatePlayer(payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api.put(`/playerstat/${payload.id}/`, data)
        .then(resp => {
          const data = resp.data;
          this.getGame({gameID: data.game})
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: could you please show your getGame() method?

Comment: Sorry, please show your entire game_store.js, are your properties declared as refs?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get rid of you getters, cause due to [pinia documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#option-stores),

> as getters you can think of as the computed properties

and you're not computing anything. So you can simply access the state properties, what you are already doing in your GamePage.vue file.

Secondly, you should also consider async/await pattern instead of Promiste.then(). Like mentioned in the comments, there's a problem with promise constructor antipattern in the OP.

I also prefer writing my pinia stores with the setup() approach, because I think it fits the vue3/composition-api approach a bit better.

```js
import { api } from 'boot/axios'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { splitPlayers } from 'src/helpers'

export const useGameStore = defineStore('game', () => {
  
  const game = ref(null);
  const teamOne = ref(null);
  const teamTwo = ref(null);

  const getGame = async (gameId) => {
    const resp = await api.get(`/games/${gameId}/`);
    const teams = splitPlayers(resp.data)
    game.value = resp.data
    teamOne.value = teams[0]
    teamTwo.value = teams[1]
  };

  const updatePlayer = async (data) => {
    const resp = await api.put(`/playerstat/${data.id}/`, data)
    const gameId = resp.data.game;
    await getGame(gameId)
  };
  
  return {
    game,
    teamOne,
    teamTwo,
    getGame,
    updatePlayer
  }
});
```

Comment: I started using Pinia from just last 2 hours, though I figured out about getters, unless I'm further modifying state values they are not necessary. I tried your code by making some modifications like storing the api response into resp variable, but the problem is still alive.

Comment: @Jitendra I updated my answer, please try using the "setup" or "composition API" way of using the pinia store.

Comment: I tried with the updated code, but no change in expected output. I'm not aware of composition API style of Pinia, thanks for that.

Comment: Setup function is for low-level usage. It doesn't differ much from writing a store yourself. What's the purpose of using it here? "your actions seem to be asynchronous but are not marked with "async" - not a problem, one doesn't need to "mark" actions, `async` functions are just functions that return a promise. There's a problem with promise constructor antipattern in the OP but that's because it's a mistake, not because of the lack of `async`

Comment: @Jitendra do you have vue-devtools installed in your browser? Its a very good tool to observe state changes in your pinia state.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd